# Insert Text into a TextBuffer via a Function - python

Tags: python, textview, pygobject, gtk-textbuffer

I have following problem:

How can i insert text in my textbuffer?

**Interface.py**

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):

        # Build our Interface from the XML/Glade file
        gladefile = "MainWindow.glade"
        try:
            self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
            self.builder.add_from_file(gladefile)
        except:
            print("Failed to load Glade file: %s" % gladefile)

        # Connect signals
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        # Get the widgets
        self.window = self.builder.get_object("MainWindow")

        ...

        # TextViews
        self.TextViewCommandInput = self.builder.get_object("TextViewCommandInput")
        self.TextViewCommandOutput = self.builder.get_object("TextViewCommandOutput")

        ...

def DrawCommandView(output):
    TextBufferCommandInput = MainWindow.TextViewCommandInput.get_buffer()
    TextBufferCommandInput.insert_at_cursor(output + "\n")
```

And import "DrawCommandView" in a file

**Commands.py**

```
from Interface import MainWindow, DrawCommandView

output = "Hello World"
DrawCommandView(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    StartMainWindow = MainWindow()
    StartMainWindow.main()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Dokumente/Workspace/project/Commands.py", line 5, in <module>
    DrawACommandView(output)
  File "/home/user/Dokumente/Workspace/project/Interface.py", line 182, in DrawCommandView

    TextBufferCommandInput = MainWindow.TextViewCommandInput.get_buffer()
AttributeError: class MainWindow has no attribute 'self'
```

**Thanks for your help!**

greetz

Answer (score 0):

When you say `TextBufferCommandInput = MainWindow.TextViewCommandInput.get_buffer()`
You are asking for a class attribute in MainWindow named TextViewCommandInput.  You don't have a class attribute TextViewCommandInput, you have an instance attribute TextViewCommandInput.  You need to pass an instance of MainWindow into DrawCommandView in order to get to TextViewCommandInput.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm new to python - so, how can I pass an instance of MainWindow into DrawCommandView?
You mean like this:
`Instance = MainWindow()
Instance.TextViewCommandInput.get_buffer()`

Now I don't get any errors, but there isnt anything in the TextView

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant---although it doesn't matter if you create the instance within the function, or create it elsewhere and pass it into the function as an argument.  I'm not familiar with gtkBuilder, so I don't think I can help much with that part.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to `set_text()` instead of `get_buffer()`.

See the [`set_text()`](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/textview.html#Gtk.TextBuffer.set_text) documentation.

Then later `get_buffer()` can retrieve the text inserted by `set_text()`.

Here are some methods I've been using to have a generic way to use the buffer.

```
def GetTextBuffer(self):
    self.text_buffer = self.text_edit.get_buffer()
    # self.text_edit is a Gtk.TextView() instance
    # to get the text buffer from TextView
    # buffer.get_text( start iterator, end iterator, bool )
    # the third argument set to True = Include hidden characters
    # third argument set to False = Don't include hidden characters
    # hidden characters would be visual formatting markup and such
    return self.text_buffer.get_text(
        self.text_buffer.get_start_iter(),
        self.text_buffer.get_end_iter(), 
        False)

def SetTextBuffer(self, to_buffer):
    # to_buffer is user input from widgets, or default values set at run time.
    text_buffer = self.text_edit.get_buffer()
    text_buffer.set_text(to_buffer)
```

Comment: That's interesting Jonas. I haven't used stackoverflow much yet, and didn't know that it was curated with this much detail.